# Add NOT keyword in iMacros

Tags: firefox, imacros

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:some<SP>text<SP>here
```

This line of code searches for the `A` tag with `text` = '`some text here`' and clicks. How can I make the iMacro do something so that it checkes the attribute text and if NOT, clicks there. for example. If `A` tag doesn't contain `already done` text, then click there. I don't think I am explaining that good.

Something like:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:NOT(some<SP>text<SP>here)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply scrape text and compare it in your javascript format script.

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:* extract=txt
```

will give you text on the tag. After it you can play with it as you want after compare.

```
if (scraped_text !== "some text here"){
do something;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use scripting. And use this trick. I found it on iopus forum and tested it myself. Works great when I need check is there an element on the page. The trick is to add CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER to the end of your command like this.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:some<SP>text<SP>here CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";

/////////Beginning//////////////

if(iimPlay(macro)==true)
{
alert("Something.");
}
else
{
alert("Something Else.");
}
```

So this script will do an event over that page element, so it will check is it there. If the script returns "true" the element is there. If it returns "false" the element is not there.

I am not sure how to implement on your case but with a little bit of thinking you can do it yourself. If you have more questions ask.

Also, this is IMPORTANT. In these kinds of macros don't add "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" or you will always get result "true" and the macro will loose it's purpose.